# Populating an MVC Model in a View using JQuery ajax with C# code behind

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In a *ASP.NET MVC* View, what is the syntax to populate a Model using JQuery's `$.getJSON` or `$.ajax`?

The MVC code behind is written in C#.

For an MVC View is there something like? -

> ```
> @model MyModel
>
> $.getJSON('@Url.Action("MyAction","MyController")/', function (dataReturned) { 
>
>     @model = dataReturned  //put the data that is returned into the Model
>
> }
> ```

Comment: I had an error in my title which I fixed. And I expanded upon the question.

Comment: And the MVC is which framework in which programming language?

Comment: The frame work is in C# (I added that to the question)

Comment: @ABogus , the framework is called "ASP.NET MVC" and **not** simply "MVC". It is referring to IE as simply "the internet". MVC is a language agnostic design pattern.

Comment: Thanks for making that clarification teresko.

Answer (score 0):

MVC is just a pattern, there are infinite ways to implement it. Tell us what languages and libraries are on the server side, and maybe we'll be able to help you.

Comment: I had a mistake in my title and I refrased the question. Hopefully it make more sense.